# This is regarding the grokparsefailure

Tags: elastic-stack, elk

This is my sample log.

> <4>Nov 19 17:08:28 BAGW-R kernel: [BlackRidge|Gateway|5.0.0.8928M]
> class="Attribution" category="Filter Rule: To_Trusted Drop"
> ctx="bump0" filterNumber="1022" src="192.168.120.173" srcPort="41178"
> dest="192.168.120.100" destPort="443" gwAction="DISCARD"
> gwMode="Enforce"

Grok pattern:

> %{WORD:class} %{WORD:category} %{WORD:ctx} %{NUMBER:fil ternumber}
> %{IP:src} %{NUMBER:srcPort} %{IP:dest} %{NUMBER:destPort} %{WORD:gwAc
> tion} %{WORD:gwMode}

I get a *grokparsefailure*.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: Are you trying to run this grok in Logstash pipeline?

Comment: What fields do you want to extract? If your message has always this format you do not need grok to parse it, you can combine the `dissect` filter with the `kv` filter.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you're getting this error because the pattern you have used does not match the logs you have provided.

[image: grok pattern does not match]

Can you be more specific what fields you are trying to capture from this log ?

I have wrote a grok pattern for the logs you must follow similar way such that it matches the whole log. In case you get found unknown escape character error use \ twice instead of  single \

```
%{MONTH:month}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY:date}%{SPACE}%{TIME:time}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:temp1}\]%{SPACE}class\=\"%{WORD:class}\"%{SPACE}category\=\"%{GREEDYDATA:category}\"%{SPACE}ctx\=\"%{WORD:ctx}\"%{SPACE}filterNumber\=\"%{NUMBER:filternumber}\"%{SPACE}src\=\"%{IPV4:src}\"%{SPACE}srcPort\=\"%{DATA:srcport}\"%{SPACE}dest\=\"%{IPV4:dest}\"%{SPACE}destPort\=\"%{NUMBER:destport}\"%{SPACE}gwAction\=\"%{WORD:gwaction}\"%{SPACE}gwMode\=\"%{WORD:gwmode}\"
```

[image: Latest grok match]

I have written the whole grok command please check if this works. I have made an assumption that u would get all logs in this format.

Use this website to test ur grok pattern: https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result

Existing grok pattern:  https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#

Comment: <%{INT:syslog_pri}>\s*%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp}\s+%{HOSTNAME:logging_host}\s+%{PROG:logging_process}(?:\[%{INT:logging_pid}\])?:\s+\[%{DATA:version}\]\s+%{GREEDYDATA:logged_message}

Comment: I tried this above pattern and I want to extract all the fields in the message string individually because I need them for my dashboard.

Comment: ya mine is not complete yet it has a lot of text fields u can follow what I have done and capture all fields

Comment: Edited my answer now it has grok pattern for the log which u have provided. If you get any error like unknown escape char error please use \\ instead of \